# How can I resize an image in an email? Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, markdown

I am trying to give a given size to an image so that it is displayed with that size in an email but it does not work.
[Here is the image I am trying to resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoDWY.png)

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

This is the code I am using.
I use this code on my blade to send mails.

```
<img style="width:570px !important;" src="{{asset('images/aspecto-proyecto/imagen_horizontal/'.$proyecto.'/'.$nombre_banner)}}" id="banner">
```

Comment: "_I am trying to give a given size to an image_" With what code, can we see that? "_but it does not work_" What does that mean? Is the image not displayed? Wrong image? Have you tried using standard HTML? Or CSS?

Comment: I would suggest posting some of the code you are using and explaining what you have tried so far. It will make it easier for other contributors to help you.

Comment: In what email client are you having the trouble? Have you tried setting a `width="570"` on the `<img>` tag?

Comment: Yes, I have set a width but it doesn't work for me.
This problem is done in outlook, not in gmail. @ceejayoz